# Polynomial in field with 8 elements

Tags: polynomials

Hello I am wondering if the following is how one would go about showing that the polynomial $t^{2}+t+1$ has no solution in $$\mathbb{F}[X]_{2} \setminus (x^{3}+x+1)$$ (irreducible polynomial of degree 3 with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$

I just listed out all the 8 elements, and all there squares,

then I wrote say $G(x)=t^2+t+1$

and evaluated at each, for example

$G(0)=0+0+1=1$

$G(1)=3=1$

$G(x)=x^{2}+x+1$

$G(x+1)=x^2+x+1$

$G(x^2)=x+3$

etc , and tried out all 8 possible values. To see that none give zero, is that sufficient to show it has no solution? Is my work even correct?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have only $8$ elements? If you have a degree $3$ extension of a finite field of size $3$, then you would get $3^3$ elements. Trying all of them would work, but it's too much work. Instead, recall the theorem that the degree of a subextension must divide the degree of the extension. If $t^2+t+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_3[t]$, then a root would generate a degree $2$ extension. Can this extension be within your degree $3$ extension?

Comment: My mistake typo it should be F2

Comment: I fixed the typo, thanks for pointing it out, but do you have any comment in regard to the fixed version?

Comment: @Quality: If it is $\mathbb{F}_2$, then you write it **before** "$[X]$", as it makes no sense after. Also, did you actually read my answer? It answers your question already without any change!

Comment: Yes I did and we have not learn what is extension or subexstenion

Comment: @Quality: Erm did you get my comment about your notation or not? The correct notation is "$\mathbb{F}_2[X] / \langle x^3+x+1 \rangle$"; it is **meaningless** to have a subscript $2$ after $\mathbb{F}[X]$, and also people use forward slash for mod, not backslash. And if you did not learn about field extensions even though that is precisely what you are asking about, then I don't know what kind of course that is. If you are serious about learning, get a good book (such as the PDF notes at http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/algebra/) and read through it. It is comprehensive yet understandable.